# Apache-FOP: gap between columns

Tags: xml, apache-fop, xmltable

I need to put a "gap" between columns of a table in Apache-FOP:

```
<fo:table column-gap="2mm" width="156mm" height="260mm" table-layout="fixed" page-break-after="always">
            <fo:table-column column-number="1" column-width="50mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-number="2" column-width="50mm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-number="3" column-width="50mm"/>

            <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt" text-align="start" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif"
                           font-weight="normal" font-size="10pt">

            // rows/cells stuff
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
```

I tried using column-gap, spacing-before, margin-left etc but the columns are sticked together yet. Any idea how to put a gap between? Maybe the only solution is creating "empty" columns?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right in my xsl-fo documents always blocks inside the table-cell elements. Gaps and distances are realized with margin attributes of the block elements.

Comment: It is my suspect too but the problem comes when you need to add a border around the cell. In that case you will not see any gap.  So at the moment the only solution I found is adding extra columns with width as the gap needed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if still relevant, but you could easily put another column that is very small between the columns that you wish to have a gap.